# useSelect in block Edit always returns default store value

Tags: block-editor

given my custom store, when I try to use readItems selector, I am always getting default store state. Selector works fine (tested in console with wp.data.select), however, it takes some time to catch values asynchronously I presume useSelect memoizes first returned value which is default store state and does not respond to store changes.

How to fix this?

Beginning of block edit function:

```
const LECTURERS_TABLE = 'tla_mit_lecturers';


export default function Edit(props) {
    const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;

    const allItems = useSelect(select => select('REST-extra_table').readItems(LECTURERS_TABLE));
```

Store:

```js
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';
import { createReduxStore, register } from '@wordpress/data';

/**
 * returns table id from table name
 * @param  {} table
 */
function getTableId(table) {
    if (! table) {
        console.log('Table name not supplied for API');
        return undefined;
    }
    const tableId = tableIds.indexOf(table);
    if (tableId == -1) {
        console.log('Wrong table name supplied to the API');
        return undefined;
    }
    return tableId;
}

// items is array of tables - item['table_name'][index] is individual item
const tableIds = [
    'tla_mit_lecturers',
]

const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    tables: [
        ['default']
    ],
};

const actions = {
    *createItem( item, table ) {
        const tableId = getTableId(table);
        const retValue = yield actions.fetchFromAPI(
            {
                path: '/extra_table/v1/item?table=' + table,
                method: 'POST',
                data: item
            }
         );
        // retValue should be ID if insert is successful
        return retValue ?
            {
                type: 'CREATE_ITEM',
                item: {ID: retValue, ...item},
                tableId
            } :
            {
                type: 'FETCH_ERROR',
                error: 'unknown'
            };
    },

    *deleteItem( ID, table ) {
        const tableId = getTableId(table);
        const retValue = yield actions.fetchFromAPI(
            {
                path: '/extra_table/v1/item?table=' + table + '&ID=' + ID,
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
         );
        return retValue ?
            {
                type: 'DELETE_ITEM',
                tableId,
                ID
            } :
            {
                type: 'FETCH_ERROR',
                error: 'unknown'
            };
    },

    *updateItem( ID, item, table ) {
        const tableId = getTableId(table);
        const retValue = yield actions.fetchFromAPI(
            {
                path: '/extra_table/v1/item?table=' + table + '&ID=' + ID,
                method: 'PUT',
                data: item
            }
         );
        return retValue ?
            {
                type: 'UPDATE_ITEM',
                item: {ID, ...item},
                ID,
                tableId
            } :
            {
                type: 'FETCH_ERROR',
                error: 'unknown'
            };
    },

    // action to set item values - hydrate in https://unfoldingneurons.com/2020/wordpress-data-store-properties-resolvers
    setItem( item, tableId ) {
        return {
            type: 'SET_ITEM',
            item,
            tableId
        };
    },

    // action to set item values - hydrate in https://unfoldingneurons.com/2020/wordpress-data-store-properties-resolvers
    setAllItems( items, tableId ) {
        return {
            type: 'SET_ITEMS',
            items,
            tableId
        };
    },

    fetchFromAPI( action ) {
        return {
            type: 'FETCH_FROM_API',
            path: action.path,
                method: action.method,
                data: action.data,
                tableId: action.tableId
        };
    }
};

const store = createReduxStore( 'REST-extra_table', {
    reducer( state = DEFAULT_STATE, action ) {
        switch ( action.type ) {
            case 'CREATE_ITEM':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    tables: Object.assign([...state.tables], {[action.tableId]: [...state.tables[action.tableId], action.item] })
                };
            case 'UPDATE_ITEM':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    tables: Object.assign(
                            [...state.tables],
                            {[action.tableId]:
                                Object.assign(
                                    state.tables[action.tableId],
                                    {[state.tables[action.tableId].findIndex(el => el.ID === action.ID)]: action.item}
                                )
                    })
                };
            case 'DELETE_ITEM':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    tables: Object.assign([...state.tables], {[action.tableId]: state.tables[action.tableId].filter((el) => el.ID !== action.ID) })
                };
            // hydrate
            case 'SET_ITEM':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    tables: Object.assign([...state.tables], {[action.tableId]: [...state.tables[action.tableId], action.item] })
                }
            case 'SET_ITEMS':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    tables: Object.assign([...state.tables], {[action.tableId]: [...action.items] })
                }
            case 'FETCH_ERROR':
                console.log('AJAX fetch error, code: ' + action.error);
                return state;

        }
                // console.error('Table name is not given!!! '+action.type)

        return state;
    },

    actions,

    selectors: {
        readItem( state, ID, table ) {
            const tableId = getTableId(table);
            if (tableId === undefined)
                return undefined;
            if (state.tables[tableId])
                return state.tables[tableId].find(el => el.ID == ID);
            else
                return undefined;
        },
        readItems( state, table ) {
            const tableId = getTableId(table);
            if (tableId === undefined)
                return undefined;
            // return empty array if state.tables does not exist
            if (! state.tables[tableId])
                console.error('Requested table does not exist in state!');
            return state.tables[tableId] || undefined;
        },
    },

    controls: {
        FETCH_FROM_API( action ) {
            return apiFetch(
                {
                    path: action.path,
                    // path: action.path,
                    method: action.method,
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    mode:'same-origin',
                    // headers: {
                    //  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    //  },
                    data: action.data
                } );
        },
    },

    resolvers: {
        *readItem( ID, table ) {
            const tableId = getTableId(table);
            const item = yield actions.fetchFromAPI(
                {
                    path: '/extra_table/v1/item?table=' + table + '&ID=' + ID,
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: null,
                    tableId
                }
             );
            return item !== undefined ? actions.setItem( item, tableId ) : undefined;
        },
        *readItems( table ) {
            const tableId = getTableId(table);
            const allItems = yield actions.fetchFromAPI({
                    path: '/extra_table/v1/all_items?table=' + table,
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: null,
                    tableId
            });
            return allItems !== undefined ? actions.setAllItems( allItems, tableId ) : undefined;
        },
    },
} );

register( store );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `allItems` gets populated ...eventually. So the code in the beginning of the block must be extended to respond when `allItems` is populated:

```
export default function Edit(props) {
const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;

const allItems = useSelect(select => select('REST-extra_table').readItems(LECTURERS_TABLE));
const [populated, setPopulated] = useState(false);

if (! populated && allItems.length !== 0) {
    // further code here
    setPopulated(true);
}
```

What I did is checking each time the block is rendered if `allItems` is populated, but saving this information in State, so code which I want to run after it is populated runs only once.